# A football cartoon with teen characters who wear black

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

It most likely aired on MBC 3. The characters don't have any super powers, they're just normal teens with different struggles. One theme you can notice between the main characters is that they wear black and practice in a gloomy field and such, not to say they're emo or punk but it was just a prominent theme.

I don't remember any character names. I do remember the team leader had a brother also on the team. The goalkeeper always wore a hoodie over his head and had a kinda rich dad who doesn't like the fact his son plays football instead of tennis. There was a girl who wore a bandana/beanie and had blondish hair and she lived with her grandma. And another character who joined the team midway through the show who also had a rich dad who does approve of his son playing football, but he wants his son to play on the team he sponsored, not the team that he's currently on with the other characters.

Their coach lived in a van beside the football field where they practice.

Last but not least, later in the show they found out that each of them own an animal skull that corresponds to them. In a game finale they used the skulls to light up the football field lines and caused a storm that kinda enhanced theirs skills so they won. There are more scientific details about the skulls and such but I really don't remember. The skulls didn't give them individual powers.

The cartoon seems to be dubbed to Arabic. While I don't know the origin, I can say it seems western(not Asian/other). I remember watching the shows roughly between 2015-2019 but not sure how long it was aired or when it was made. The animation was 2D so I would say hand-drawn.

Comment: re: " they found out that each of them own an animal skill that corresponds to them" how powerful is this animal skill? Is one skill that of a Cheetah? (and thus he is twice as fast as a human?) Or maybe a skill of a bull, so when he charges, he blows right through the other team? Or Eyes of an eagle, so when he throws, he always hits his target? etc. etc.  IF the animal skills make them much superior to normal human skills, that could be a fantasy element.

Comment: MCB3 looks like it might be an Arabic Children's TV station. Do you know IF the shows were local origin? or Dubbed from another language to Arabic? Any indication of the original language? (i.e. The name of the football station, or team names on the scoreboard.)

Comment: In roughly which year did you watch this and when do you think it might've been made? Also, was the animation hand-drawn or computer-generated?

Comment: They used skulls (the head bone(s)) or skills?  They discovered that they own animal skills, or animal skulls?  I'm guessing that you intended to write "skills" in all those places, but I do not want to edit without truly knowing what you meant.

Comment: To reply to the comments: the cartoon seems to be dubbed to arabic, while I dont know the origin, I can say it seems western(not Asian/other). I remember watching the shows roughly between 2015-2019 but not sure how long it was aired or when it was made. The animation was 2D so I would say hand-drawn. For the skulls(not skills), I want to clarify they didnt give them individual powers, as I said they somehow used the skulls as a team to light up their football field & caused a storm, the storm then kinda enhanced their skills & helped them win at the end, I cant remember the details

Comment: are you sure it is not Inazuma Eleven Go? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inazuma_Eleven_GO_(season_1)#Episodes

Comment: see if this rings a bell also https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1178508/

Comment: Thanks but I already found the answer. Appreciate your efforts though, both these recommendations were close

Answer (score 6):

I managed to find the series. It's called [*The Wild Soccer Bunch*](https://www.wunder-werk.de/the-wild-soccer-bunch/?lang=en). There are movies and [novels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wild_Soccer_Bunch) alongside the animated series.

> The production of the story and the cool “look” of the program is of exceptional high quality, unusual and wild. The result is a soccer-saga that engrosses and thrills viewers, with characters who are always on the go and, in spite of all their faults, succeed in rising above themselves. Fiction for strong kids full of passion and emotion.

[image: Image of the soccer players, largely wearing black]

The 18th episode, "Das Geheimnis der Tierschädel", is [about mystical animal skulls](https://programm.ard.de/TV/Programm/Sender/?sendung=280083461389702).

> 18. **Das Geheimnis der Tierschädel**
>     Jojo überglücklich, als Conny einen Job im Museum findet. Denn seine Mutter braucht eine feste Arbeitsstelle, damit Jojo endlich aus dem Waisenhaus zu ihr ziehen kann. Theumer, der Sponsor des Museums, erfährt von der Sache, und gibt Jojo den Hinweis, dass eine Ausstellung über Tierschädel den Direktor bestimmt von Conny überzeugen würde. Sein Hintergedanke ist, so endlich an die Tierschädel aus dem Teufelstopf zu kommen. Nichts ahnend greift Jojo die Idee auf, und die Wilden Kerle steuern ihre vier Totem-Schädel aus dem Teufelstopf zur Ausstellung bei. Doch am Vorabend der großen Eröffnung werden alle Schädel geklaut! Conny fürchtet, ihren neuen Job direkt wieder zu verlieren, wenn die Ausstellung platzt. Doch so schnell geben die Wilden Kerle nicht auf: Markus entdeckt eine Spur, die zu seinem Vater führt und kann gemeinsam mit Jojo die Schädel in einer halsbrecherischen Aktion zurückerobern. Im letzten Moment stellen die Wilden Kerle eine Ersatzausstellung auf die Beine und Conny behält ihren Job. Die Wilden Kerle fragen sich, was Theumer mit den Schädeln vorhatte und untersuchen sie genau. Dabei entdecken sie mysteriöse Zahlen, die in die Schädel eingraviert sind.

Google Translate:

> 18. **The Mystery of Animal Skulls**
>     Jojo is overjoyed when Conny finds a job at the museum. Because his mother needs a permanent job so that Jojo can finally move out of the orphanage and live with her. Theumer, the museum's sponsor, finds out about the matter and tells Jojo that an exhibition about animal skulls would definitely convince the director of Conny. His ulterior motive is to finally get the animal skulls from the devil's pot. Unsuspecting, Jojo takes up the idea and the Wild Things contribute their four totem skulls from the devil's pot to the exhibition. But on the eve of the grand opening, all the skulls are stolen! Conny fears that she will lose her new job again if the exhibition is canceled. But the wild guys don't give up so quickly: Markus discovers a trail that leads to his father and, together with Jojo, is able to recapture the skulls in a breakneck operation. At the last moment, the Wild Guys put on a replacement exhibition and Conny keeps her job. The Wild Things wonder what Theumer intended to do with the skulls and examine them closely. They discover mysterious numbers engraved on the skulls.

Comment: Added mention of 18th episode. FWIW, in the series, they battle teams comprised of vampires, and fae creatures that live in the mists, so this is definitely SF&F.

Comment: You can accept your answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: The other teams are "common" children too, but the author is able to give all the storylines something special by describing the imagination of children very impressive. For SF qualifies the story about a match of this youngsters agains iconic famous players from all ages :)